# ImageView - Collision Detection

Tags: android

I want to check if two ImageViews are colliding. My Figur(Resolution: 50x50) and my Star(Resolution: 30x30). The figurGR is there because when my figure is moving left or right it gets thinner and so I have to subtract some pixels.

Here is the code for the collision check:

```
if(((Figur.getX() + figurGR > Star.getX() && Figur.getX() + figurGR < Star.getX() + 30) || (Figur.getX() + (50 - figurGR) > Star.getX() && Figur.getX() + (50 - figurGR) < Star.getX() + 30)) && ((Figur.getY() > Star.getY() && Figur.getY() < Star.getY() + 30) ||(Figur.getY() + 50 > Star.getY() && Figur.getY() + 50 < Star.getY() + 30))) {

                    points++;
                    placeStar();
        Points.setText("Stars: " + points);
    }
```

and that is the code for moving my Figure around:

```
 @Override public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                fx = Figur.getX();
                fy = Figur.getY();


                    if (event2.getX() > event1.getX() && Math.abs(event2.getX() - event1.getX()) > Math.abs(event2.getY() - event1.getY())) {

                        fx = fx + 25;
                        Figur.setX(fx);
                        Figur.setBackgroundResource(figure_swipe_r);
                        figurGR = 10;



                    } else if (event2.getX() < event1.getX() && Math.abs(event2.getX() - event1.getX()) > Math.abs(event2.getY() - event1.getY())) {

                        fx = fx - 25;
                        Figur.setX(fx);
                        Figur.setBackgroundResource(figure_swipe_l);
                        figurGR = 10;



                    } else if (event2.getY() > event1.getY() && Math.abs(event2.getX() - event1.getX()) < Math.abs(event2.getY() - event1.getY())) {

                        fy = fy + 25;
                        Figur.setY(fy);
                        Figur.setBackgroundResource(figure_swipe_u);
                        figurGR = 0;



                    } else if (event2.getY() < event1.getY() && Math.abs(event2.getX() - event1.getX()) < Math.abs(event2.getY() - event1.getY())) {

                        fy = fy - 25;
                        Figur.setY(fy);
                        Figur.setBackgroundResource(figure_swipe_h);
                        figurGR = 0;



                    }

                    return true;
            }
```

Maybe it isn't working because: If i go down directly on the star none of the corners of my figure is inside of the star. So I need to check if the sides collide.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: do not tag `image-collision` - you are got just two rectangles. it's just `+`/`-` case.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i am new to programming and don't see a diffrence between colliding a rect and an image...

Comment: If you got two 100x150 rectangles bitmaps (images) with just single pixel in the middle (or the rest is background/transparent) when would you consider them collided - when the rectangles start to overlap or when rather when image content (dots)?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski when the pixels overlap, all pixels even transparent. Thats why i tagged Pixel-Collision